# When my application send to Background From Activity D which is SingleInstance ,Relauch it from Long Press Home 

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my Problem .

My Activity A as normal Activity ,now Activity A call Activity B with normal intent now Activity B Call Activity C.Now i have One Activity D which i declare as SingleInstance

```
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Now when i start my Activity D from Activity C by Intent ,now let see one case in which user is on my Activity D now user press home key and now he reach at Home Screen of my Android mobile.Now User Long Press in Home key and there are list of recent Apps in which user press my application and my application show Activity D which is current but real problem start when user press back key it send to Home Screen which i don't expected it should show me Activity C which is Caller to Activity D.

Can any one help in problem for application lunch from recent application list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now For Come out From this Problem i do Following thing .

As i Said Activity D is Single Instance declare in Android Manifest ,Now Activity D have

```
onNewIntent(Intent intent)  @Override
```

Now i add Following Code in this Method .

```
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Activity D.this, Activity C.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intentStart);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to put the code in the onCreate() of Activity D.  Thanks, this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always
>   the single and only member of its task

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

so you must remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` from manifest file or change override Back button functional in your Activity D.

Comment: But using SingleTask will help me to send my Activity D to back using moveTaskToBack(true); in that Activity when i done with Activity D use.

Comment: And My problem happen only when user leave application from Activity D and then he start application from Recent apps by pressing long press home .

Comment: It's happend because "singleTask" run only Activity D when your application is resumed. Try to remove this and you'll see the difference.

Comment: i have  use SingleTask which in response in not expected behavior which i get from singleInstance.

Answer (score 0):

did you read this 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode ???

- singleTask
  The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.
- singleInstance
  Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.

Comment: ,Yes i have already read that and i remove my activity D as `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.Because we found that it is not appropriate for our application.Thanks for your Response.